# Putty like app for android

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, putty

I need pure putty like app that can be used to connect aws instance without any bloated features, or How can I access my Amazon EC2 instance from my Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at
https://github.com/jackpal/android-command-line-ssh. Behind the scenes android is pretty much a linux machine, there are terminals you can get straight from the playstore.